# Uso del dunder__slots__ en Python

Tags: python

El concepto del dunder [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) lo comprendo a la perfección. Básicamente es otro modo de almacenar los atributos de un objeto para evitar el uso de diccionarios, que pueden llegar a resultar lentos en grandes cantidades.
Esta pregunta está más orientada a *cómo funcionan entonces cosas como la jerarquía de herencia* con este tipo de objetos.
En un caso de uso común de POO en Python ocurriría algo así...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.edad = edad
    def __str__(self):
        return f"""
        Nombre   = {self.nombre}
        Apellido = {self.apellido}
        Edad     = {self.edad}
    """

persona_nueva = Persona('Pepe','Ramos',33)
print(persona_nueva)
```

En este caso, la representación gráfica sería...

```
Persona       ----> { __init__ -> code
                    { __str__  -> code

persona_nueva ----> { nombre   -> "Pepe"
                    { apellido -> "Ramos"
                    { edad     ->  33
```

En este caso, cuando tratamos de acceder a un atributo de `persona_nueva` si el intérprete no lo encuentra, irá a buscarlo a la clase `Persona`, la cual es en sí misma un objeto.
Pues bien, ¿cómo seria este procedimiento en caso de que los atributos de `persona_nueva` estuviesen en un `slot`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
class Persona:
    __slots__ = ('nombre', "apellido", "edad")
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.edad = edad
    def __str__(self):
        return f"""
        Nombre   = {self.nombre}
        Apellido = {self.apellido}
        Edad     = {self.edad}
    """

persona_nueva = Persona('Pepe','Ramos',33)
print(persona_nueva)
```

El hecho de que el código corra a la perfección ya nos indica que se hace exactamente lo mismo que en caso del uso común de `__dict__` (dado la utilización de `__str__` al imprimir `persona_nueva`).
Sin embargo el funcionamiento no puede ser el mismo.
Por ejemplo el *protocolo descriptor* (el hecho de que el intérprete vaya a buscar descriptores a la clase `Persona` antes de acceder a los atributos de `persona_nueva`) se debe evitar, ya que de entrada no se pueden usar descriptores con este tipo de objetos.

Tengo muchas dudas acerca del tema, sin embargo, con que se me responda esta única podría deducir todas las respuestas: *¿cómo hace el intérprete para acceder a los atributos tan rápidamente cuando éstos se almacenan en `__slots__`?*
Teniendo en cuenta que un caso de uso común sería donde `__slots__` fuere una tupla, una secuencia ordenada, que se supone, es es igual de rápida que una mapeada como el caso de los diccionarios.

Comment: Toda tu pregunta se reduce a "¿por qué es más rápido usar `__slot__`?" Sería conveniente que respaldaras esa afirmación con mediciones objetivas contra el método estándar.

Comment: @CandidMoe si, exactamente

Comment: El hecho de que _corra a la perfección_ no indica que hace exactamente lo mismo, sino que logra devolver el mismo resultado. Sabemos que la implementación es diferente. Ya que comienzas diciendo que comprendes el tema _a la perfección_, francamente, no le encuentro el sentido a la pregunta cómo esta planteada. Creo que básicamente lo que quieres saber es cómo funcionan los _slots_ a bajo nivel, para lograr esa ganancia en eficiencia (tanto de tamaño como de velocidad), ¿no?

Comment: @jachguate diste justo en el blanco

Comment: Ok, desconozco el tema y no tengo la suficiente motivación para ir a investigarlo por mi mismo, pero sospecho que hay que darse una vuelta por los foros de desarrolladores de python (no los que usan python para desarrollar, sino los que usan c para desarrollar python), o ir a ver el código fuente.

Comment: Mi sospecha, es que cuando usas _slots_, se almacena solo el valor de los atributos en una especie de lista o arreglo, al que se accede por la posición. Dado que ya no tienes que almacenar el nombre de cada atributo, ahorras espacio en memoria. Dado que las posiciones son fijas en toda la jerarquía, ahorras tiempo en el acceso. Pero, como ya he dicho, no puedo confirmarlo.